# Sending Data From Form to be Displayed in Another View Android

Tags: java, android, string, variables, android-intent

I'm trying to display text that is input by the user if it is not null but I'm having some trouble (I'm a Java noob). Here is the flow of my app:

Starts at **Main.java** with a button:

-Button: **Profile**

If you click profile, the app goes to the profile page **Display.java** that also has a button:

-Button: **Edit Profile**

-This view also displays the information (name, phone number, zip code, etc)

When a user clicks Edit Profile, the program goes to a form at **EditProfile.java**, which has a form where users enter the information and then there is a button to submit.

-Button: **Submit**

This submit button takes the user back to the previous view (Display.java) and displays the information that was previously entered in the form with the string **resultText**.

I'm not sure how to make this work. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate the help!

Edit: One thing to note is that I'm getting a "Dead Code" error on the if expression in Display.java

**Display.java:**

```
public class Display extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    TextView resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String firstName = null;
    String lastName;
    String phoneNumber;
    String city;
    String zipCode;

    if(firstName != null) {

        firstName = bundle.getString("EditTextFirstName");
        lastName = bundle.getString("EditTextLastName");
        phoneNumber = bundle.getString("EditTextPhoneNumber");
        city = bundle.getString("EditTextCity");
        zipCode = bundle.getString("EditTextZipCode");
        resultText.setText("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + newline + "Phone Number: " + phoneNumber +
        newline + "City: " + city + newline + "Zip Code: " + zipCode + newline);
    }

    Button profile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    profile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Display.this, EditProfile.class));             
        }
    });
}   
}
```

**EditProfile.java:**

```
public class EditProfile extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);       

 }
public void sendFeedback(View button) {
    final EditText firstnameField = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.EditTextFirstName);
    String firstname = firstnameField.getText().toString();

    final EditText lastnameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextLastName);
    String lastname = lastnameField.getText().toString();

    final EditText phoneNumberField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextPhoneNumber);
    String phoneNumber = phoneNumberField.getText().toString();

    final EditText cityField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextCity);
    String city = cityField.getText().toString();

    final EditText zipCodeField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextZipCode);
    String zipcode = zipCodeField.getText().toString();

    int count = 0;
    int fnlen=firstname.length();
    int lnlen=lastname.length();
    int phlen=phoneNumber.length();
    int citylen=city.length();
    int zclen=zipcode.length();

    if (fnlen<=0){
        firstnameField.setError("Enter your first name");
    }
    else {
        count += 1;
    }



    if (lnlen<=0){
        lastnameField.setError("Enter your last name");
    }
    else {
        count += 1;
    }


    if (phlen<=0){
        phoneNumberField.setError("Enter your ten digit phone number");
    }
    else if (phlen!=10){
        phoneNumberField.setError("Phone number must be ten digits");
    }   
    else {
        count += 1;
    }

    if (citylen<=0){
        cityField.setError("Enter your city");
    }
    else {
        count += 1;         
    }
    if (zclen<=0){
        zipCodeField.setError("Enter your Zip Code");
    }
    else if (zclen!=5){
        zipCodeField.setError("Enter a five digit zip code");
    }
    else {
        count += 1;
    }   

    if (count == 5) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this,Display.class);
        intent.putExtra("EditTextFirstName",firstnameField.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("EditTextLastName",lastnameField.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("EditTextPhoneNumber",phoneNumberField.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("EditTextCity",cityField.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("EditTextZipCode",zipCodeField.getText().toString());

        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        count = 0;
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `Intent  i= getIntent();
        if(i.getExtras()!=null){

```
        firstName = bundle.getString("EditTextFirstName");
    lastName = bundle.getString("EditTextLastName");
    phoneNumber = bundle.getString("EditTextPhoneNumber");
    city = bundle.getString("EditTextCity");
    zipCode = bundle.getString("EditTextZipCode");
    resultText.setText("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + newline + "Phone Number: " + phoneNumber +
    newline + "City: " + city + newline + "Zip Code: " + zipCode + newline);
    }`in your Display Class instead of firstName != null) { ...} and let me know if any queries.
```